# Save count attempts in c#

Tags: c#, list, count

i try to attempt 10 random questions but the problem is when i click button then this starts over again wheres as i want to continue until 10 questions will attempt there is 2 buttons one is check anwer  and other is next question
on next question button question is displayed but this starts from over e.g if 1 question is attempt then want to display 2nd question not again to attempt from start

next question button code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    num1 = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    num2 = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    rnd1.Text = num1.ToString();
    rnd2.Text = num2.ToString();
    label2.Text = "";
}
```

check answer code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    int answer = Convert.ToInt32(txt_answer.Text);
    if((num1+num2)==answer)
    {               
        label2.Text="Correct!";
        correctans++;
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text="Incorrect! correct answer is " + (num1 + num2);
        wrongans++;
    }
    txt_answer.Text = "";
    rnd1.Text = "";
    rnd2.Text = "";
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.Add(num1);

    int c = list.Count;
    if(c==10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("YOUR CORRECT ANSWER ARE  " + correctans + " AND INCORRECT ANSWER ARE  " + wrongans);
    }
}
```

now how to attempt 10 questions at a time and then display message

**update**

i am trying to do when 1 question is answered then want to display next question means 2nd questions .. like

```
1) 2 + 2 = .....
```

here when user type 4 and click check then message display correct and when i check count in this line `int c = list.Count;` this shows 1  then when user click next question then want to display next question e.g

```
2) 3+4=...
```

now here when i check count this shows again 1 where as i want to (2) not (1) because next question is start

Comment: it is pretty unclear what you are trying to do and what have you tried to solve this ?

Comment: you getting any can't convert `int to string` errors as well?

Comment: check update please

Comment: no i am not getting any error

Answer (score 0):

Take this line out of the functions:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
```

So that your list to be declared as Form Class member and not in the scope of the button2_Click event handler.

Also add to `if(c==10)`

```
list.Clear()
```

So that after 10 answers list clear.

Change you button2_Click to this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
    int answer = Convert.ToInt32(txt_answer.Text);
    if((num1+num2)==answer)
    {               
        label2.Text="Correct!";
        correctans++;
    }
    else
    {
        label2.Text="Incorrect! correct answer is " + (num1 + num2);
        wrongans++;
    }
    txt_answer.Text = "";
    rnd1.Text = "";
    rnd2.Text = "";

    list.Add(num1);

    int c = list.Count;
    if(c==10)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("YOUR CORRECT ANSWER ARE  " + correctans + " AND INCORRECT ANSWER ARE  " + wrongans);
        list.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: what i add and what i remove?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is *Magic button* antipattern: do not cram everything in `*_Click`, extract logic:

Data:

```
  private int m_Corrects;
  private int m_Wrongs; 
  private int m_Attempts; 

  private int m_Number1;
  private int m_Number2;

  private static Random s_Random = new Random();
```

Business logic:

```
  private void NextProblem() {
    m_Number1 = s_Random.Next(1, 10); 
    m_Number2 = s_Random.Next(1, 10); 

    txt_answer.Text = "";

    // Be nice, put keyboard focus on the textbox
    if (txt_answer.CanFocus)  
      txt_answer.Focus();

    label1.Text = $"{m_Number1} + {m_Number2} = ?";  
  }

  private void Attempt() {
    m_Attempts += 1; 

    int answer;

    // what if I enter "bla-bla-bla"?
    if (!int.TryParse(txt_answer.Text, out answer)) {
      m_Wrongs += 1; 
      label2.Text = 
        $"{txt_answer.Text} is not a number! Correct answer is {m_Number1 + m_Number2}";
    }
    else if (m_Number1 + m_Number1 != answer) {
      m_Wrongs += 1; 
      label2.Text = 
        $"Incorrect! Correct answer is {m_Number1 + m_Number2}";
    }
    else {
      m_Corrects += 1; 
      label2.Text = "Correct!";
    }

    if (m_Attempts >= 10) {
      m_Attempts = 0;

      MessageBox.Show(
        @"YOUR CORRECT ANSWER ARE {m_Corrects} AND INCORRECT ANSWER ARE {m_Wrongs}"); 
    }
    else 
      NextProblem();  
  }
```

Then call these methods

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    NextProblem(); 
  }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Attempt(); 
  }
```